# Why is Bootstrap not rendering my html correctly?

Tags: html, css, frameworks

Basic issue: I am trying to create a navbar at the top of a website. I am using the Bootstrap framework, and believe that I have properly brought in all relevant libraries. However, when I try to view my html in a browser, none of the elements are properly stylized. What am I doing wrong? My code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/71aad8ed5d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <title>Looplab</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">LoopLab</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
                <span class="navbar-toggle-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#home" class="nav-link">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#explore-head-section" class="nav-link">Explore</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#create-head-section" class="nav-link">Create</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#share-head-section" class="nav-link">Share</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" 
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" 
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        //Get the current year for the copyright
        $('#year').text(new Date().getFullYear());

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What mistake am I making?

Answer (score 0):

Open the developer tools in your browser. Look at the Console. Read the error messages.

> Refused to apply style from 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.3/css/bootstrap.min.css' because its MIME type ('application/xml') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

So you can then check out the URL —  https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.3/css/bootstrap.min.css — which leads to an error page.

Find a different CDN or download the CSS file and host it locally.

Comment: Thank you so very much! I am new to coding and still learning the ropes. I hadn't though to check the developer tools. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar problem before and what I was told to do was put the link to the CSS file above the link to the Bootstrap file. Otherwise the Bootstrap will override the HTML elements.

Comment: Hey. I tried moving the style.css link above the Bootstrap link, but it doesn't look like it has made any difference.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help, I don't have much experience in Bootstrap and just thought we might have had the same problem.

Comment: No worries. The answer up above had it right: I was pointing to the wrong link for my Bootstrap css, which was what was causing the issue.

Comment: Oh okay, I'm happy your problems solved and kudos Quentin for spotting that.